# DateTime Conversion Error - Excel to SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I have two data sets on two different SQL servers.  I've got dataset 1 and put it into Excel and am then going to put this into a temp table so I can query it against the data on server 2.  Here is the SQL code that I have created:

```
    Create table #JWTemp1 (AutoID varchar(10), IDNumber varchar(20), AltIDNumber varchar(20), AdmitDTTM datetime, AdmitDay varchar(15), AdmitWeekNo int)

Insert into #JWTemp1 Values('ID001','BCC445567','ABC445567','42510.7326388889','Friday','21')
```

Each time I try and run the code, I get the following error:

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I know this is a common error but I've tried all manner of soutions and got nowhere.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is `42510.7326388889`  --  I don't believe this is a valid `datetime` format, and therefore can't be converted?  Can you explain what that string means?

Comment: When I pull the datetime from my original SQL query and paste it into excel, this is the format it presents it in.  I suppose I can do a conversion in SQL before hand and put it into the correct format - this might work

Comment: The actual datetime value is: 2016-05-20 17:35:00.000

Comment: @Jimmy That is how Excel sees the date.  You will need to convert it back to a string that SQL will see as a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, non of the answers provided seemed to work.  However, I solved the issue using the following logic:

```
Create table #JWTemp1 (AutoID varchar(10), IDNumber varchar(20), AltIDNumber varchar(20), AdmitDTTM datetime, AdmitDay varchar(15), AdmitWeekNo int)

Insert into #JWTemp1 Values('ID001','BCC445567','ABC445567','42510.7326388889','Friday','21')

Select
convert(datetime, Convert(float,AdmitDTTM))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to format the string. Not sure what DB are you using but here is the syntax for mySql.

```
DATE_FORMAT(colName, '%Y-%m-%d') DATEONLY
DATE_FORMAT(colName,'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY
```